# Inserting array number in file path using bat file

Tags: batch-file

I created manually 8 folders

I want to copy target files to dest as follows

```
target31  => dest31
target32  => dest32
target33  => dest33
target34  => dest34
```

So I have written as below which is not working

```
31 32 33 34 should be array and end of the filename(target,dest) should be array to match file name
```

I tried this but not working

```
@echo off
set list = 31 32 33 34
(
    for %%a in (%list%) do (
        xcopy /s C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\check\target%%a C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\check\dest%%a
        echo %%a
    )
)
```

Comment: Raghu Nandan, I have added the information from the comment above to your question, by using the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62822281/edit)** button, please do that yourself in future. Can you also now delete the comment above, as it is no longer needed. You also need to modify your `set` command, to use the correct syntax, `set "list=31 32 33 34"`; currently you have a variable named `%list %`, which menans that `%list%` = nothing. _Of course you could just change `%list%` to `%list %`, but I wouldn't recommend it as a preference over changing the `set` command._

Comment: I would also recommend that you doublequote your file paths, as standard practice, whilst there are no visible spaces or poison characters in your provided example, it's still a good habit to have. Also for extra safety, provide the path to xcopy, and its extension, that way, you will not have to rely on variables which are often accidentally or unknowledgeably modified. `"%__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\target%%a" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\check\dest%%a\" /S`.

Comment: `set list = 31 32 33 34` does not set the variable `%list%`. It sets the variable `%list %` i.e. the variable whose name is `ell eye ess tee SPACE`. Use that and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this will be to put the numbers in the two Brackets `(31 32 33 34)`.
Also,you should put file paths between two double quotes.

Try my code :

```
@echo off
for %%a in (31 32 33 34) do (
 xcopy "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\check\target%%a" "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\check\dest%%a" /S
)
```